# Bounded intervals of $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$

Tags: general-topology

The topology $\mathcal{T}$ in $\overline{\mathbb R}=[-\infty,+\infty]$ consists of sets of the form $(a,b), [-\infty, a), (a, \infty]$ and any union of segments of this type, where $a,b \in \mathbb R$ are arbitrary real numbers.

> **Question.** Who are they, if there are, the bounded intervals of $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That question makes no sense. The concept of bounded subset is defined for metric spaces, but not for topological spaces.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantosMaybe I explained myself wrong. That is, in $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology (which induces the usual metric) the limited intervals are those of the type $[a,b]$, $(a,b]$  or $[a,b)$ At this point who are those of the extended real line?

Comment: How do you define “bounded” in the extended real line? If you say that a subset $S$ of $\overline{\mathbb R}$ is bounded if and only if there are $a,b\in\overline{\mathbb R}$ such that$$(\forall x\in S):a\leqslant x\leqslant b,$$then every subset $S$ of $\overline{\mathbb R}$ is bounded.

Comment: A set is bounded when it is a subset of a compact  set.

Comment: For the reals, bounded means order bounded. In $\overline{R}$ any subset is bounded, as $-\infty$ and $+\infty$ are its minimum resp. maximum.

Answer (score 0):

The bounded intervals of a linear order are sets like (a,b), [a,b],  [a,b), and (a,b].
In $\bar R,$ as it has endpoints, all intervals are bounded.